# jQuery plugin to change panel contents depending on anchor selection?

Tags: jquery

If I have a panel, the content of which should change, based on a menu selection, is there a jQuery plugin or widget that would do this?

```
Choice A Anchor |  Choice B Anchor |  Choice C Anchor
_____________________________________________________



                   PANEL CONTENTS



_____________________________________________________



<div class="contents-a">Content A</div>

<div class="contents-b">Content B</div>

<div class="contents-c">Content C</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems like [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) is what you want,

correct?